# Ionic2 + Angular2 - Attempted to assign to readonly property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm using ionic refresh api, which lets page to be pulled and refresh with updates.

angular2 page on refresh method.  I want to clean existing rows and then add new rows with `.push()` method. when I clean property with `this.rows = []` I get following error.

> 8     470644   error    EXCEPTION: TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property. in [rows in ListPage@25:30]

Is there any other way of cleaning previous array for `this.rows` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So don't reassign rows array, modify existing one:

```
this.rows.length = 0;
```

Setting array length to `0` effectively clears array (in place, by modifying it).

Comment: that's nice, I didnt know that. I will try soon after I get my ionic app up again. it got completely broken after update lol (known issue for them)